# What is an on-disk structure?

Tags: sql, indexing

An index is an **on-disk structure**.

I couldn't find anything understandable.

For example, I found this
[Is it like a file system?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the index is physically stored on disk, as opposed to "only exists in-memory".

Your link is not related at all.